# Tagging Adobe Documents with Foundation

Tags: search, tagging

Does SharePoint Foundation support the concept of tagging Adobe Acrobat documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Tagging is not supported in SharePoint Foundation.  It is included in both Standard and Enterprise editions.

An excellent editions comparison chart is [available here](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx).